# UTF-8 encoding for Yaml file

Tags: regex, encoding, utf-8, yaml

I am trying to encode the following string, as I want to use it as
a regex requirement within a yaml file. I keep getting the error "The YAML values does not appear to be valid UTF-8"

```
parameters:
  user_reg:      "[a-zA-Z0-9\s'\-$&_*+#!?§]+"
```

I tried with the following, but still getting the same error:

```
parameters:
  user_reg:      "[a-zA-Z0-9\s&#39;\-$&amp;_*+#!?§]+"
```

Whats the correct UTF-8 term for my expression?

Comment: Well... *is* the file encoded as UTF-8?! The problematic character is most likely "§".

Comment: Yes the problem was the "§" character, thanks a lot. At first I had this in an xml file and the "§" character was no problem there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the first expression, but ensure that your file is encoded as UTF-8. You can check (and change) this using for example Notepad++.

Comment: The comment of deceze was the cause, and your answer will help me in future to check for errors. Thanks :)